# NodeJS/React_Accessing a local variable

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have this code below which will  allow me to get the user selected option but the problem i couldn't access the local variable ,

the code is below

```
let gender=""

const handleAddrTypeChange = (e) => { 
   console.log((addrtype[e.target.value]))
   gender =addrtype[e.target.value] 
}

console.log(gender)
```

What I'm looking for is reading the value `gender` which is actually undefined

Any help is welcome,
Best Regards

Comment: Use `state` instead of mutable local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to have a 'variable' and update it based on an action, and then use the updated value elsewhere, you should use `state`

```
const [gender, setGender] = useState('');

const handleAddrTypeChange = (e) => { 
   console.log((addrtype[e.target.value]))
   setGender(addrtype[e.target.value])
}

console.log(gender)
```

updating a components state will rerender the component with the new value for `gender`.  Setting a variable like in your example will not rerender the component